# WebClient.UploadString does not give json

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying following code, but it gives me response string in HTML, but I want it in JSON.

```
string _sendGridAPIUrl = "http://localhost/MyServiceHost/Testing/TestService";
            string data = "{\"applicateRegionCode\":\"N\",\"MyID\":\"737\", \"sourceVersion\"=\"6\", \"DivisionName\":\"AE Name\",\"JobTaxName\":\"Test List\",\"Username\":\"jnam\",\"Schema\":\"TTT\"}";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
                client.Headers.Add("id", "13a94672-08k6-46a8-89cc-ba3217721504");
                client.Headers.Add("key", "354C5TA7-330D-40DC-8524-0000500DE654");

                var str = client.UploadString(_sendGridAPIUrl, data);
```

Comment: Does your service require a *POST* instead of a *GET*? `UploadString` is a POST operation. In any case, WebClient is obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.

Comment: Perhaps your service returns an *error page* instead of HTML? Instead of writing a JSON string by hand use a strongly typed class and convert it to JSON with JSON.NET and `var json=JsonConvert.Serialize(myDto);

Comment: Got it. I had to add ?format=json to the URL. i.e. "http://localhost/MyServiceHost/Testing/TestService?format=json"